# Programatically get "Always On" property of Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure

Is there any way to programmatically access "Always On" of App Service property in Azure using C#?

Thanks,
Vishal D.

Comment: If it's possible it's quite likely to be listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/

Comment: Try the [Web Apps - List REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/rest/api/appservice/webapps/list?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5001077).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites) and **`callUpdateConfigurationAsyn`**c

```
var credentials = GetCredentials(/*using certificate*/);
using (var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(credentials))
{
    var currentConfig = await client.WebSites.GetConfigurationAsync(webSpaceName,
                                                                    webSiteName);
    var newConfig = new WebSiteUpdateConfigurationParameters
                    {
                        ConnectionStrings = null,
                        DefaultDocuments = null,
                        HandlerMappings = null,
                        Metadata = null,
                        AppSettings = currentConfig.AppSettings
    };
    newConfig.AppSettings[mySetting] = newValue;
    await client.WebSites.UpdateConfigurationAsync(webSpaceName, webSiteName,
                                                   newConfig);
}
```

If you want to use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/) to update the settings, keep in mind before updating the settings use the list settings api to get the  settings